# Tapping into protected Twitter streams using Tweepy/Python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am writing a small Twitter Bot using Tweepy as the Python Twitter wrapper and I am trying to access tweets that were written by my friends whom Twitter account is set to private.
The bot follows them and vice versa but for some reason I cannot tap into those tweets from protected friends.
This is the snippet of the code that deals with the Twitter Stream:

```
auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=[hotword])
```

Anybody has a hint how to do it right?
Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stream/filter API won't return protected content.

From the [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/post/statuses/filter):

> Returns **public** statuses that match one or more filter predicates.

You can't even see them using the [follow parameter](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#follow) that specifies users you are interested in for the Streaming API:

> indicating the users whose Tweets should be delivered on the stream. **Following protected users is not supported**.

To get protected tweets you will need REST endpoints.